# Is any elegant way to make a list contains some integers to become a list contains some tuples?

Tags: python

I have a list

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Is any elegant way to make them work in pair?
My expected out is

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)]
```

Comment: "Is there an elegant way..." In Python, the answer is always yes ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
pairs = zip(*[iter(a)]*2)
```

is a common idiom

Comment: Can you add an explanation?

Answer (score 6):

```
[(a[2*i], a[2*i+1] ) for i in range(len(a)/2)]
```

This is of course assuming that len(a) is an even number

Answer (score 3):

```
def group(lst, n):
    """group([0,3,4,10,2,3], 2) => [(0,3), (4,10), (2,3)]

    Group a list into consecutive n-tuples. Incomplete tuples are
    discarded e.g.

    >>> group(range(10), 3)
    [(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8)]
    """
    return zip(*[lst[i::n] for i in range(n)])
```

From activestate, a recipe for n-tuples, not just 2-tuples

Answer (score 1):

```
b = []
for i in range(0,len(a),2):
    b.append((a[i],a[i+1]))
a = b
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it using slices and zip.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> zip(a[::2],a[1::2])
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)]
```